# Generate Letsencrypt certificate for another server

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, certbot

I am working on an application which allows companies and people to spin-up their own public blockchain with one click. For now blockchain consists of single node. The spinned up blockchain node is running on AWS, and it is under our management, and not customer's.

After creating the EC2 instance for blockchain, we are creating a target group and binding it to an ALB with certificate which has the domain `*.rpc.route3`. The prefix part is randomly generated in runtime.

So the end result in the eyes of a customer is that they have a blockchain node running on our AWS account, which they can access and send requests through a URL something like `https://ajk1232k.rpc.route3`.

**THE GOAL**

I want customers to be able to bring their own domains, and CNAME their domain to the domain of the blockchain node (`*.rpc.route3`). But if the user doesn't have certificate, I would like my backend server to generate the certificate. And I am using Letsencrypt compatible certbot for this purpose. Also, I want to avoid generating the certificate on the blockchain node since it would require Ansible, and I prefer avoiding it unless absolutely necessary. Here are the overall steps to achieve this:

- Customer adds the rpc domain as CNAME to their own domain
- Customer sends us the domain to generate the certificate for him
- We generate a certificate, and now he can use his own domain to access the blockchain node

**THE PROBLEM**

In order to be able to do this without Ansible, I need to generate the certificate on the backend server, and then send it to the node instance, or maybe somehow make certbot point to that node instance and tell it to make validation there etc. As far as I researched, I don't know how can this achieved with certbot, because it requires an acme-challenge and loops back to itself to see if the domain is the current machine.

**THE QUESTION**

Can I use certbot to generate a certificate for another server? Maybe a way to make it generate only challenge first, then I can put that challenge file as a static response to the ALB, and then tell it to validate now? I am also open to any other trust-worthy lets-encrypt implementations if they would be of help.